# Chat over LAN in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, chat, write

I am trying to set up a LAN chat with two users using Linux server and none of them is root.

I have tried this two methods:

`write account_name` on both computers

And:

`nc -l port_number`  on first computer
`nc IP_adress port_number`  on second computer

But the problem is whenever I write something and person on the other side hits enter it breaks also my line e.g:

I am typing: "This is just a sim<kbd>enter</kbd>ple text". And this <kbd>enter</kbd> from another person breaks my line.

Is there way how can I fix that? Or another way I can set up this chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `talk` and `talkd`.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talkd_and_the_talk_command and http://linux.die.net/man/1/talk for details.

Comment: I've tried this before but every time I get an eror: "error on read from talk deamon"

Comment: It might be a firewall restriction. Please check if talk (517/udp) and ntalk (518/udp) are allowed. Does local `talk` work?

Comment: I've checked etc/services file. Is that what you wanted? There are these lines about this: talk               517/tcp      # like tenex link, but across machine - unfortunately, doesn't use link protocol (this is actually just a rendezvous port from which a tcp connection is established)
talk               517/udp      # like tenex link..(same as up)
ntalk              518/tcp
ntalk              518/udp

Comment: I don't know how to check local talk.

Comment: test local talk by starting the talk daemon on the host, and using two sessions try to talk to each other. For example: `session1 # talk user@myhost pts/2`. See if user in `session 2 #` gets an invitation and follow instruction from message to start chat. Use `who` to get the right terminal (pts/X) to use.

Comment: Still the same error for user_1 and nothing happened in user_2

Comment: It's common for talk messages to be disallowed by default.  Try getting both users to run `mesg y`.  see `man mesg` for more info.

Comment: Can you check the entries for `talk` and `ntalk` in the `/etc/(x)inetd.conf`? See if those are enabled? If not, enable those entries and restart `(x)inetd`. Besides that, try to use the IP address instead of the hostname to connect.

Comment: both "enabled = " and "disabled = " fileds are empty but I cannot change that. I can only read that file

Comment: what is the output of: `netstat -an|egrep ":517|:518"`?

Comment: The output is empty

Comment: That means that the `talkd` daemon is not started. You might be lucky to restart the `inetd` service, otherwise try to get the disabled/enabled parameters right in the config file and have the inetd service restarted.

Comment: I cannot find the way to restart the `inetd`. I've tried with this command: `kill -HUP inetd` but I get an error: `arguments must be bumbers of processes`. Anoyone could help? And how I can change the config file if I don;t have acces to it?

Comment: I've found the nuber with `ps` but I get message: `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Contact the system administrator to perform the configuration for you. Or decide to use another approach, two `nc` sessions, one for messages from user_1 to user_2, and one for messages from user_2 to user_1

Answer (score 1):

maybe with tmux and netcat:

```
mkfifo cf ; tmux new "cat cf" \; split -h "nc -l  1234 > cf" ; rm cf   # server
mkfifo cf ; tmux new "cat cf" \; split -h "nc $IP 1234 > cf" ; rm cf   # client
```

... or full version based on same tools:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# lanchat script, server: "./lanchat", client: "./lanchat serverIpAddr"

port=1234 ; [ -z "$1" ] && target='-l' || target="$1"
LOG=$(mktemp) ;    trap 'rm "$LOG"' EXIT INT TERM HUP

tmux new "watch -n1 cat $LOG" \; split -l 1 \
  "  while read ME; do echo \"> me: \$ME\" >> $LOG ; echo \"\$ME\" ; done \
   | nc $target $port \
   | while read HE; do echo \"< he: \$HE\" >> $LOG ; done"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have X11, `Pidgin` or `iptux` do LAN chat.

https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/11/use-pidgin-for-chatting-and.html

https://github.com/iptux-src/iptux